# What does {% capture var %} do in jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

What does `{% capture var %}` do in Jekyll?

Can I for example, in a .md file do:

```
{% capture head %}
I am the head
{% endcapture %}
```

and then in the .html file do:

```
{{head}}
```

Am I using capture correctly?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`capture` lets you assign text to a variable name. Later on when referencing that variable you can output that text.

In your above example `head` is the variable name. So you're saying, place all of the text between the opening and closing capture tags in a variable named `head`.

Then later in `{{head}}` you're saying you'd like to dump the contents of that variable onto the page. There is nothing special about the name `head` and you could rename it to something else entirely.

You can find more information about `capture` on this [Liquid for Designers page](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers)

Comment: The [Shopify documentation for Liquid](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/tags/variable-tags#capture) is also an excellent resource. In my opinion it is organized better than the Liquid for Designers page and usually has better descriptions, examples, and sample output.